# Is anyone overridden Mapper run(Context) method in your implementations?

Tags: hadoop, mapper

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#method.summary

**run (Context)** method of **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper**

```
a). Expert users can override this method for more complete control over the execution of the Mapper.
```

1. Currently what is the default behavior of run(Context) method.
2. If i override run(Context) what kind of special **control** will get as per the documentation?
3. Is anyone overridden this method in your implementations?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Currently what is the default behavior of run(Context) method.

The default implementation is visible in the Apache Hadoop source code for the [Mapper](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java#L136-L151) class:

```
/**
 * Expert users can override this method for more complete control over the
 * execution of the Mapper.
 * @param context
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);
  try {
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
      map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
  } finally {
    cleanup(context);
  }
}
```

To summarize:

1. Call `setup` for one-time initialization.
2. Iterate through all key-value pairs in the input.
3. Pass the key and value to the `map` method implementation.
4. Call `cleanup` for one-time teardown.

> 2. If i override run(Context) what kind of special control will get as per the documentation?

The default implementation always follows a specific sequence of execution in a single thread.  Overriding this would be rare, but it might open up possibilities for highly specialized implementations, such as different threading models or attempting to coalesce redundant key ranges.

> 3. Is anyone overridden this method in your implementations?

Within the Apache Hadoop codebase, there are two overrides of this:

- [`ChainMapper`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/chain/ChainMapper.html) allows chaining together multiple `Mapper` class implementations for execution within a single map task.  The override of `run` sets up an object representing the chain, and passes each input key/value pair through that chain of mappers.
- [`MultithreadedMapper`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html) allows multi-threaded execution of another `Mapper` class.  That `Mapper` class must be thread-safe.  The override of `run` starts multiple threads iterating the input key-value pairs and passing them through the underlying `Mapper`.